# Rehash PDF document using iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have a scenario in which I need to create data to be signed hash and send it to the signing server after which signer certificate details are received from the signing server which needs to be used in the signature appearance object that was created in the first step and create rehash data to be signed bytes and respond to signing server.
The resultant signature is invalid in this scenario.
Could someone help me out in this regard?
My code base is following:

```
            Stream readerStream = new MemoryStream(documentBytes);
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(readerStream);
            pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader,outputStream,new StampingProperties());

            pdfSigner.SetFieldName("Signature1");
            signatureAppearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
            signatureAppearance.SetLayer2Text("test");
            signatureAppearance.SetLocation("test");
            signatureAppearance.SetContact("test");
            signatureAppearance.SetPageNumber(1);
            signatureAppearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);

            PreSigning external = new PreSigning(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,PdfName.ETSI_CAdES_DETACHED,"SHA256");
            pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(external,estimatedSize);
            docHash = external.getHash();
```

- **Problem Statement:**

After sending the above hash to the signing server I got the signer certificate details which need to be updated in signature appearance layer2 text and I need to compute the hash again which results in an invalid signature.

Comment: If you throw away your first signature anyways, why not start by signing an arbitrary value first and only thereafter,  using the returned certificates, prepare the pdf.

Comment: @mkl
The only hash to be signed is passed between the signing application and the signing server and this hash to be signed is recalculated after getting certificate information but after embedding the resultant PKCS7 signature in PDF, it say the document is altered after the signature is performed.

Comment: If you change the hash, you obviously need a new signature. Otherwise the signed data obviously is altered.